# How can I insert predefined value in a particular column of big query table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I want to write one small python utility job which will load data from 2 type of files(say one is "SourceA", another is "SourceB") present in GCS bucket. Both csv files have columns in same numbers, name and order,therefore my resulting bigquery table will have same columns. My requirement is to add one more column in bq table as "Source" which will tell us any particular row is from which file (from SourceA or SourceB).

In python to load data from CSV file into bq table, I use following command-

```
bq load --replace --skip_leading_rows=1 `<tablePath>` <filepath>
```

How can I do something like we do in SQL -

```
insert into tableName(col1,col2,col3,...coln) as select col1,col2,...coln-1,"SourceA" from table2;
```

Comment: I'd suggest it may be cleaning to simply read your predictions in as a new table, then run a SQL join to get them attached to your existing data. Do you have a common key to join on?

Comment: See if this is useful. You can create an external table: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-sql-data-languages-ddl-and-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews